# High-level overview of system architecture of LUKS/cryptsetup (how it works vs. how to setup)

Tags: reference-request, disk-encryption

I've been searching (unsuccessfully) online for a high-level overview of how LUKS/cryptsetup disk encryption works. I am reading through the cryptsetup source code to try to understand what is going on "under the hood", but my limited knowledge of C (and crypto code in particular) is making it difficult to understand how everything fits together.

I was wondering if short of reading the sources, there was a way to simply describe/visualize the major sub-systems of LUKS/crypt-setup, and the role they each play in creating secure disk encryption (i.e. the rationale behind the architecture).

I've found plenty of decent online guides that describe *how to setup* a LUKS/cryptsetup. For example:

- [How to set up an encrypted filesystem in several easy steps](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/469/How_to_set_up_an_encrypted_filesystem_in_several_easy_steps)
- [HowTo: Linux Hard Disk Encryption With LUKS](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/)

... but very few of these types of "how to" articles actually go into the details of the overall architecture and *why* certain commands are being typed in. So it makes me feel like I'm just blindly typing in commands without really understanding what they are doing, and the implications of each on the overall security of the system.

I'm looking for something that doesn't necessarily focus on *how to install* LUKS/cryptsetup, but rather focuses on "high-level" discussion and diagrams covering the basic *system  architecture*, along the lines of these articles for other crypto subjects (just as a few random examples):

- [The Advanced Encryption Standard (Rijndael)](http://www.quadibloc.com/crypto/co040401.htm)
- [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)
- [Let's Encrypt - Technology](https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks/technology/)

Could someone either share a pointer to such a references, or share a brief overview of the LUKS/cryptsetup here?

Comment: Does [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup) help you?

Comment: I've already seen the manual, and it has some information in it that was helpful. But like I said above, I'm less interested in learning *how* to use cryptsetup/LUKS (which is very easy to find documentation for) and more interested in articles/diagrams that describe the system architecture and the reasoning behind why things were designed/setup the way they are, and what the security implications are of using different LUKS/cryptsetup configurations, etc.

Comment: How about this? https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf

Comment: @fkraiem Thank you! That was exactly the kind of thing I am looking for, as far as LUKS is concerned. I'll read it more carefully, and continue digging for similar documents describing dmcrypt/cryptsetup, and the implementation of LUKS with cryptsetup.

Comment: @fkraiem Digging through the references of the article you shared, I came across a paper that covers everything I was looking for (how LUKS works, how it defends against known disk encryption attacks, and how it's implemented with dm-crypt). Here's a link to the paper if other folks come here later looking for similar info: http://tomb.dyne.org/New_methods_in_HD_encryption.pdf  [Forwith, Clemens, "New Methods in Hard Disk Encryption" (2005)] ... Once I've read all of this more carefully, I'll write up a summary as an answer here, if nobody more knowledgeable choose to do so. Thanks again!